# AJAX data and text box data not storing together

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, ajax

I am using Ajax to send information about the screenwidth to a PHP page and I am also wanting the user to type a value into a text box however this is currently not working as only the textbox value is passed and I am told that the other value is an undefined index. Any help would be appreciated.

**HTML/JS page**

```
<form method="post" action = "insert.php">
  <input type = "text" name ="carName" id ="carName"/>
    <div id ="screenWidth" name = "screenWidth" method="post"></div>
  <input type="submit" id= "submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
var screenWidth = screen.width + "px"; 

document.getElementById("screenWidth").innerHTML = screenWidth; 
console.log(screenWidth) 

var TestVal = ("test");
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'insert.php',
        data: {'screenWidth': screenWidth},
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
      }
      });
```

**PHP Page**

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

    $screenWidth = $_POST['screenWidth'];
    $screenHeight = $_POST['screenHeight'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
    $screenWidth = $_POST['screenWidth'];
    $phoneType = $_POST['carName'];


    echo 'hello';


   $sql = "INSERT INTO deviceInfo (screenWidth, carType, )
     VALUES ('$screenWidth','$carType',)";

     if (sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record has been added successfully !";
     } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . ":-" . sqlsrv_errors($conn);
     }
     sqlsrv_close($conn);
}


?>
```

Comment: If you want to post using ajax then you need to get data on variable and post like screenWidth.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your setup.

1) only form inputs are submitted with the form. When you click the submit button, the form will submit through a browser HTML post and your JS will not be run. The form submit will only submit the carName variable in the post data as the screenWidth is not in a form input.

2) the JS you have written will only submit the screenWidth over ajax - and that will run as soon as the page is loaded (assuming this is only an extract and that this JS is in side a jQuery(document).ready(function($){ }) block.

3) your carName becomes carType and then phoneName in your code, so $carType is not set when you insert your SQL.

You have 2 options here.. 
1) change you div containing the screenWidth to a text input that is readonly. This way you can populate your screenWidth on page load and then have the user submit the form over HTML post when they are finished updating the carName. This will not use AJAX, or

2) get rid of the form and create a "click" function for submitting your AJAX that includes both vars... something like this (not tested).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
     e.preventDefault();  // stop the button from posting
     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'insert.php',
       data: {'screenWidth': $("#screenWidth").text(),
              'carName': $("#carName").val()},
       success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
       }
     });
  });
});
```